# c# client and netty server

Tags: c#, client, netty

I have met a question, Our client project is in c#, and want to communicate with netty based server, I have to do packet encapsulation manually as I have not found netty library written in c#. If written in java client, It's so simple like below:

```
ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(opcode,protocol,
NettyUtils.writeStrings(username,password,refKey),udpAddress);
```

but above code written in c# without 3-rd library support, It's a big workload, anyone can give me some advice on how to implement netty client in c#, thanks.

Comment: Why you would want to use netty from c# ? You can use whatever network framework that exist for c# here..

Comment: I have a similar situation and some of our clients run in C#, so we want to build software that accommodates them.

Comment: Are you trying to provide a client library or publish the protocol you support so they can build their own C# clients?